# Azure AD B2C redirect loop after successful login

Tags: api, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to use Azure AD B2C for authentication & authorization in my dotnet core web app and web api by using this [example project](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2):

1. I have a dotnet mvc web app as frontend that fetches data (todo items) from the web api:
2. registered an application in my B2C tenant and use another app registered in Azure AD for openID connect authentication.
3. The login & authentication works (see the following screenshot), but after login, the browser is in redirect loop between my b2c instance url and my localhost (https://localhost:44316/signin-oidc, see the screenshot below). The url https://localhost:44316/signin-oidc is set up as redirect url in my application registered in B2C tenant, but the path `signin-oidc` does not actually exist in my mvc web app. I guess this is why the redirect loop happens (?).
4. Relevant code from my app:

   - MVC app Startup.cs:

```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
           {
               services.AddControllersWithViews();
               services.AddOptions();

               services.AddAuthentication(AzureADB2CDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                   .AddAzureADB2C(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options));

               // Token acquisition service based on MSAL.NET
               // and chosen token cache implementation
               services.AddWebAppCallsProtectedWebApi(Configuration, new string[] { Configuration["TodoList:TodoListScope"] }, configSectionName: "AzureAdB2C")
                       .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();


               // inject dependencies
               services.AddScoped<ITokenAcquisition, TokenAcquisition>();
               services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
               services.AddScoped<HttpClient, HttpClient>();
               services.AddScoped<ITodoListService, TodoListService>();            

               services.AddRazorPages();
           }
```

- The web API controllers use the `[Authorize]` attribute to protect the API. I also exposed the API in the application registered in Azure AD tenant and set scope for it. API permissions has been admin consented/granted as well

What might be the cause of the redirect loop? should we use different redirect URI in the registered application in B2C tenant?

[image: Login through B2C]
[image: redirect loop after login]

Comment: You might be able to see something in the logs if you increase logging for the Microsoft category to Trace or Debug. It could be that it is unable to read the state cookie for example, due to the recent SameSite cookie changes etc.

Comment: I believe I may be seeing this same issue using msal.js v1.2.1: I'm always getting two login dialog popups. I also haven't implemented "login-oidc", since I have no idea how it should be implemented if at all.

Comment: Did you check the response from b2c to see if tokens are issued?

Comment: Is your web api protected ?  Also why are you not using addSignIn instead of AddAuthentication ?

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this?